# What is a word to describe a toxin that is ubiquitous but in trace amounts?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word to describe a toxin that exists ubiquitously in small amounts?

Comment: traces - may be ?

Answer (score -1):

Its effects would be *insidious* - proceeding in a gradual, subtle way, but with harmful effects.

It, itself, would be common and dilute, or diluted.

Comment: -1 It's toxic only in significant concentrations.